# Mocked instance of final class in Spock behaves differently in test and dev code

Tags: java, javafx, groovy, webview, spock

In my JavaFX application I am using Spock and Groovy for testing.
I have dedicated `WebBrowserController` for taking care of my JavafX `WebView` component. I wanted to test some functionalities that depend on current Location and Document of the `WebView`.

Relevant part of WebBrowserController:

```
public WebEngine getEngine() {
    return panel.getWebView().getEngine();
}
```

This is how I create an instance of `WebBrowserController` for my tests.
Notice the `GroovyMock` I used there - ordinary `Mock(...)` does not work for final classes and `WebEngine` is a final class.

```
WebBrowserController getMockedControllerWithDocument(Document document) {
    WebBrowserController controller = Mock(WebBrowserController)
    controller.getEngine() >> GroovyMock(WebEngine) {
        getDocument() >> document
        getLocation() >> "some random string"
    }

    controller
}
```

The line below is under the test and it breaks. I would expect "some random string" to be returned but I just get failed test and NPE.

```
String url = controller.get().getEngine().getLocation()
```

Now the interesting part - I have examined the instance of `WebEngine` in two places - at the end of `getMockedControllerWithDocument` and at the line pasted above. What I found out is that it referenced the same object. Yet, when I invoked any of the stubbed methods outside of test code I was hit by NPE - `getLocation()` executed the actual implementation and not the stub (the original method is not just a simple getter and it uses a wrapped value in between).

Summing it up: why the hell does the exact same object behaves differently depending on the place its methods are being invoked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `GroovyMock`, `GroovySpy` and `GroovyStub` only work as you expect for Groovy classes. When called by Java classes, they behave like normal Spock mocks. This is documented [here](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.2/all_in_one.html#GroovyMocks):

> #### TIP
>
> When Should Groovy Mocks be Favored over Regular Mocks? Groovy mocks should be used when the code under specification is written in Groovy and some of the unique Groovy mock features are needed. ***When called from Java code, Groovy mocks will behave like regular mocks.*** Note that it isn’t necessary to use a Groovy mock merely because the code under specification and/or mocked type is written in Groovy. Unless you have a concrete reason to use a Groovy mock, prefer a regular mock.

Comment: It does answer my question, thanks! Any suggestions on how could I mock final class instance then?

Comment: You can use Mockito or PowerMock in combination with Spock, if configured correctly. But usually when someone wants to use PowerMock, IMO it is a bad smell and rather a call to refactor than to use dirty tricks. The answer depends on your exact situation, but you could e.g. also provide wrapper methods `getDocument()` and `getLocation()` in your controller and then stub them easily. Why would you test that your mock actually returns another mock? But I can feel your pain because you are dealing with an external final class. So you do have options, decide for yourself.